# useEffect with exhaustive deps loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When `modal.error` sets to `true`, then my effect should be run:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (modal.error) {
    setModal({...modal, prompt: false})
  }
}, [modal]);
```

modal - is an object:

```
const [modal, setModal] = useState<SomeInteface>({
  success: false,
  error: false,
  prompt: false
})
```

However i want in `useEffect` deps only `modal.error`, but when i do so, linter warns me about exhaustive/deps annoying rule, why should i put my entire object in to a deps array, instead of just one of its properties. It's obviously going for infinite loops, because object `modal` is always going to change.

I still don't get, why did React team went away from lifecycle's paradigm which was so convenient instead of this 3 in one thing, which is more confusing with these exhaustive/deps rules, i've read a lot of articles about `useEffect`, but still, i think lifecycles is much better.

**UPDATE 1**

```
const removePartner = (): void => {
  setModal({
    ...modal,
    prompt: false
  });
  deleteRequest(undefined, modal.id).then((resp: any) => {
    if (resp) {
      setModal({ ...modal, success: true });
    } else {
      setModal({ ...modal, error: true });
    }
  });
};
```

**UPDATE 2**

TSX part:

```
<Swal
  show={modal.prompt}
  icon={Icons.warning}
  title="Warning!"
  text="Are you sure?"
  cancelButton={true}
  onModalClose={() => setModal({ ...modal, prompt: false })}
  onAccept={removePartner}
/>
<Swal
  show={modal.error}
  icon={Icons.error}
  title="Error"
  text={fetchError!}
  onModalClose={() => setModal({ ...modal, error: false })}
/>
<Swal
  show={modal.success}
  icon={Icons.success}
  title="Success!"
  text="You have removed a user!"
  onModalClose={() => {
    setModal({ ...modal, success: false });
    doFetch().then();
  }}
/>
```

Comment: you have this problem because you only use one object for your entire state. Split it if you want to be more precise with the deps. - Btw, how do you use `prompt` ? Is it just for conditional rendering ? In that case you don't need to have this extra-field in your state

Comment: `prompt` triggers my modal window on click. Then when user clicks ok, it switches to false, and another modal shows "success" or "error" depends on the response from backend.

Comment: Can you add the entire code ? I don't think that you have unneeded states

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel i've added my function that caused me to use `useEffect()`. I need to close `prompt` modal when user clicks "OK", then my delete request fires and "success" or "error" modal shown.

Comment: add the JSX also please, where you actually use the state

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel added

Comment: Well I'm not a huge fan of the prop `show`, especially that you always have only one modal at a time. I would rather have a `status` which is either prompt, success or error and only render the correct component. That way you would replace your state object by a single variable and it would simply your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my mind about using objects in `useState` hooks, they are meant for a primitive values, that makes sense, otherwise i recommended others to use `useReducer` for complex objects. Then you won't have issues with `useEffect` deps loops cause of the whole object changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need an useEffect. You just need to bind your state to the modal.

`<Modal open={modal.error} />`

You just need a condition to set the state of modal.error